# Proof of Partial Sum - Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

By considering the partial sums for $S$, that is $$S_n =1+2+3+···+n$$ show that the infinite series $S$ does not converge.

How do we show that this does not converge? How to rigorously prove it

Thanks

Comment: If it converges, it has to be bounded.

Comment: if it converges, $S_n - S_{n-1}\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

This follows immediately if you already know that convergent sequences are bounded, or know the Cauchy criterion. If not, you can construct a proof using the definition of convergence:

Suppose $S_n$ converges to some limit $L$. Then by definition of convergence there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n>N$ we have
$$|S_n-L|<1$$
(by picking $\epsilon = 1$.)

We have that
$$|S_{n+1}-L|=|S_n-L+(n+1)|> |-1 + (n+1)|=n$$

which is a contradiction because $n\geq1$, but we require $|S_{n+1}-L|<1$.